# how to convert a special charater to null value

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I want to convert a special character into null value how can i do that??
[image]

i am making a following loop

```
     count=[]
     for j in df:
         for i in df[j]:
             if i=="?":
                  print (np.empty(1))
                 count.append(np.empty(1))
             else:
                 print (i)
                 count.append(i)
```

this loop can convert "?" into [nan] but not into null value

**so if i use    df.isnull().sum() then it will give me some null values**

Comment: By "null value" do you mean `None`?  What happens if you just replace `np.empty(1)` with `None`?

Comment: if i use             df.isnull().sum()       then it will give me some null values

Comment: @AbbeGijly  that is not list this is a data frame and so many columns have "?" inplace of null  this loop will replace "?"

Comment: @Samwise        if i use df.isnull().sum() then it will give me some null values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using for-loop with Pandas, then there is 98% chances you are doing something incorrect. You have multiple options.

```py
df.replace('?', np.nan)
```

Or

```py
df=df.where(df=='?', None)
```

`np.nan` is better than None. When reading data you can pass in a list of NaN values:

```py
missing_values = ["n/a", "na", "?", "missing"]
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", na_values = missing_values)
```

You can also map

```py
missing_values = ["n/a", "na", "?", "missing"]
mapper = {m:np.nan for m in missing_values}

df = df.replace(mapper)
```

Comment: thanks it works but not complited my task    i want if i use df.isnull().sum() then it will give me null values of my data frame

Comment: In most cases use `.isna()` over `.isnull()` to get missing values